# AngularJS get form inputs without binding

Tags: forms, data-binding, angularjs-scope

I'm building my first application with AngularJS, but i have run into a little problem.

I got a table where i render every user in users array like below:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Active</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                <td>{[{ user.id }]}</td>
                <td>{[{ user.firstname }]}</td>
                <td>{[{ user.lastname }]}</td>
                <td>{[{ user.email }]}</td>
                <td>{[{ user.company }]}</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td><a href="#modalUpdateUser" ng-click="getUser(user)" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This works perfectly fine, as i have in my controller.js an array $scope.users that gets filled with the users.

The problem is the last Cell with the the ng-click="getUser(user)", which opens a ModalBox and fills the inputs with the existing users data.

```
$scope.getUser = function(user) {
    $scope.user = user;
};
```

In the ModalBox all the input fields has ng-model="user.firstname" etc.
So this ofcourse Binds the input fields in the ModalBox to the user in my table, and instantly changes the data in the table when i change it in the ModalBox.

But what i want is to edit the data in the ModalBox and then only change the user in the table if i press "Save" in the ModalBox.

So my question is, can i take user object from the ng-repeat in my table and hand it over to my $scope.user which is bound to my ModalBox inputs without keeping them all bound together?

Thanks in advance,

- Rasmus Knudsen

**Solution** The solution was to use angular.Copy to transfer an object without the binding reference. Working example here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure suggested solution @MaxWillmo will work, objects are copied by reference & will get updated.. as it's changed in the popup?

I think you might want to do 'angular.copy()' & make a copy of the selected user, then replace the user object in the array after the editing is done.

-Bhaskara

http://blog.liftoffllc.in/search/label/angularjs

Comment: Thank you very much, the Copy was exactly what i was looking for. I also found a working example with a form here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `$scope.selectedUser` object and a `$scope.selectedIndex` property in the `getUser()` function and past the index instead:

```
getUser(index){
    $scope.selectedIndex = index;
    $scope.selectedUser = $scope.users[index];
}
```

And then use `$scope.selectedUser`to populate the modal. Once the user clicked OK you can replace the user in the array using the index.

```
saveUser(){
    $scope.users[$scope.selectedIndex] = $scope.selectedUser;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though i already tried this and Angular binds the objects references anyhow.

Comment: You could mock the selectedUser as a new object by copying over the properties you want to a new object on the scope. Then when you are done you could copy them back over.